# Unix print loop outputs on one line

Tags: bash, unix

I created this script and I want to print the outputs on one line, how do I do this?
This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter start and stop numbers"

read start stop

while [ $start -lt $stop ]

do

echo $start

start=`expr $start + 1`

done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `printf` or `echo -n`. Also, try to use `start=$(($start + 1))` or `start=$[$start + 1]` instead of back ticks to increment the variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter start and stop numbers"
read start stop
while [ $start -lt $stop ]
do
    printf "%d " $start
    start=$(($start + 1))
done
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter start and stop numbers"
read start stop
while [ $start -lt $stop ]
do
    echo -n "$start "  # Space will ensure output has one space between them
    start=$[$start + 1]
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
echo -n $start
```

Check out:
http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html

Answer (score 0):

for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)); do echo -n $i; done; echo -e "\n"

Comment: Can you explain what your code does, and how it improves on the code in the question.

Comment: I agree with @Michelle - please also format your answer and use code formatting.